# TMUX and Proxies?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tmux

I have a program that I want to run in a TMUX sessions, Is it possible to have a Proxy specific for this Tmux?  I want the other programs that I have running to stay on the address of the VPS.

Answer (score 0):

Tmux uses the environment settings of your bash shell. If you have a reason to use another settings, you can export them after instantiating the tmux and run your program. The other shell instances won't have that tmux specific environment setting available.

Comment: Just to clarify so if I start the TMUX environment and  set the proxy and start my program the other programs won't be affected as it is in A sandbox (virtual machine type) setting?

Comment: It should not be. You can cross check by opening other terminal and checking the value of defined variable and comparing with value in TMUX terminal.

Comment: I have set the following in my TMUX terminal 



export http_proxy=username:password@proxy-server-ip:8080

export https_proxy=username:password@proxy-server-ip:8082

export ftp_proxy=username:password@proxy-server-ip:8080

exprot no_proxy=localhost, 127.0.0.1

but the IP didn't change as I could still see the actual IP on the site I was visiting.


set | grep -i proxy Does show that the proxies have been changed to the data I switched to.

Comment: You need to read more about what can be set at terminal and what can't be controlled from terminal.